# ionic2 - add log out in sidemenu

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am using `sidemenu` template to begin my app. I want to add a button in `sidemenu` for user to launch a `logout` alert modal to confirm logout. Here are my code:

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';

import { Home } from '../pages/home/home';
import { Profile } from '../pages/profile/profile';
import { Logout } from '../pages/logout/logout';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = Home;

  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public logout:Logout) {
    this.initializeApp();

    // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Home', component: Home },
      { title: 'Profile', component: Profile }
    ];

  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }

  logoutApp(){ ///<-- call from static button
    this.logout.presentConfirm(); ///<-- call 
  }

}
```

**app.html:**

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
      <button ion-item (click)="logoutApp()">
      <!--Add this static button for logout-->
        Log Out
      </button>
    </ion-list>

  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { Home } from '../pages/home/home';
import { Profile } from '../pages/profile/profile';
import { Logout } from '../pages/logout/logout';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    Home,
    Profile,
    Logout
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    Home,
    Profile,
    Logout
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**logout.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  template: ``
})
export class Logout {
  constructor(
    public alertCtrl: AlertController
  ) { }

presentConfirm() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Confirm Log Out',
    message: 'Are you sure you want to log out?',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Log Out',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Logged out');
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  alert.present();
}

}
```

Based on my knowledge this should be sufficient. However I got an error:

> 45EXCEPTION: Error in ./MyApp class MyApp_Host - inline template:0:0
>   caused by: No provider for Logout!

But why do we need `provider` here? Is there something I missed out?

Answer (score 2):

`Logout` isn't a provider (it's a component), yet you're trying to inject it into `MyApp`. From the looks of it, it doesn't look like your intention is really to make the `Logout` a component. In which case, you should instead `replace` the `@Component()` with `@Injectable()`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Logout {
}
```

Then remove it from the `@NgModule.declarations` and `@NgModule.entryComponent`, and add it to the `@NgModule.providers`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // Logout
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    // Logout
  ],
  providers: [
    Logout
  ]
})
class AppModule {}
```

If `Logout` *is* supposed to be a component and you want to be able to access a method from it inside `MyApp`, what you should do instead is create a service that can be injected both into the `Logout` and `MyApp`, that can make use the service functionality to present the alert.

Comment: I figure out my problem. However, for education purposes, why should we make alert `injectable`? why can't it be `component`? I am rather new in `ionic2` and `angular2` so I am not sure how different they are.

Comment: Because it's supposed to be a service not a component. Components and services are completely different concepts. Components are for displaying views, and services are just to abstract business functionality

Comment: Thank you sir! This saved my time a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

I figure out what happen. I over think the solution.

With `alert controller` we don't need another component. just add the `alert controller` straight to `app.component.ts` then call the `presentalert()` function:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform, AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';///<-- add AlertController
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';

import { Home } from '../pages/home/home';
import { Profile } from '../pages/profile/profile';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = Home;

  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public alertCtrl: AlertController
  // , public logout:Logout
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();

    // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Home', component: Home },
      { title: 'Participate', component: Participate },
      { title: 'Adopt', component: Adopt },
      { title: 'Result', component: Result },
      { title: 'Profile', component: Profile }
    ];

  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }

  presentLogout() { ///<-- call this function straight with static button in html
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Confirm Log Out',
    message: 'Are you sure you want to log out?',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Log Out',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Logged out');
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  alert.present();
}
}
```

You don't even need a component.

Comment: I agree, it should not be a provider or component, just a function in app.ts. In my case I'm also using an AuthService provider that does all the back-end and cookie session management for the logout. Thanks for the question/answer--it's now a good example for others. The only time you need a logout component is if you want to show a special Logout page to the user, which is rare.